# Goaccess web socket failing on Safari after LetsEncrypt Sep 30 expiry

Tags: websocket, openssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, goaccess

I'm aware of the Sep 30 LetsEncrypt cert expiration and have made the necessary changes to CentOS ca-certificates.

This has fixed SSL/TLS on the mail server and php.

I'm now still getting an error with my Goaccess web stats service which provides live stats over an SSL web socket.

```
WebSocket network error: OSStatus Error -9807: Invalid certificate chain
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue ?  It connects ok in Firefox but gives this error in Safari.

Comment: Well, what does the certificate chain look like?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk How do I find that out ?